# Problema com Django Cache Page/URL

Tags: django

Encontrei um problema em usar o `@cache_page(60 * 15)` do Django no meu caso. O primeiro usuário que dar o primeiro F5, a pagina vai ficar travada com o usuário DELE logado. Então mesmo que eu entre com um outro usuário, a página ficara com a conta do outro usuário preso no cache. Isso é ruim.

Tentei usar aquele cache no template, mas o problema da performance vem da VIEW então não rola.

A questão é: meu filter é muito pesado e já fiz diversos ajustes para diminuir. Ele chega a fazer uma média de 180ms a 200ms em DEV e em produção vai lá pros 300-400ms. Isso é um delay grotesco no meu caso.

Quando usei o cache do Django pela URL ou esse cache_page foi pra 8ms, ficou lindo. Mas nada é perfeito. Gostaria de saber se alguém tem alguma alternativa ou saiba como trabalhar com esses casos.

Essa é minha configuração no `settings.py`

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
        'LOCATION': 'unique-snowflake',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você chama de "problema" ao usar o `@cache_page(60 * 15)` na verdade não é um problema é somente ele fazendo o seu trabalho corretamente. Não tenho como dar uma solução definitiva para o seu caso, porém posso colocar alguns cenários e você tenta encontrar o que mais "combina" com seu problema. Vou dividir em dois casos principais. Levando em conta que você tem um filtro muito pesado (para uma query) você precisa se responder a seguinte pergunta:

**Todos os usuários tem a mesma resposta para essa query?**

- Caso sua resposta seja sim, talvez você não precise de cache na pagina e sim na própria query, existe algumas formas de fazer isso no django de maneira otimizada e caso a resposta seja sim você estará em um cenário "confortável".
- Caso a resposta seja não, provavelmente o "usuário" faz parte dessa query que você montou. Sendo assim para cada usuário pode existir uma resposta diferente e temos um problema um pouco maior. Um cache na própria consulta pode ajudar, porém você vai utilizar o id do usuário em alguma forma de hash para identificar que aquela query (salva) corresponde a um determinado usuário. Esse problema é um pouco maior, pois dependendo do tamanho da sua aplicação essa cache (do próprio django) pode consumir muita memoria e você ainda vai precisar ficar de olho na sua estrutura de servidores, pois a consulta pode já estar em cache em uma das duas instancias do servidor e não na outra (caso seu servidor tenha múltiplas instancias).

Esse problema de cache em paginas dinâmicas é bem grande na internet, por isso algumas paginar usam o cache no próprio navegador.

Comment: No meu caso a resposta é sim, a query é a mesma para todos os usuários. O problema que encontrei é que, por exemplo, o johnny cache é para python 2.7 e versoes antigas do Django. No meu caso, esto usando a versão 1.10 e python 3. Sua resposta está certa, é exatamente o que preciso, cache no queryset, porém está dificil encontrar algo que realmente funcione para minha versão. Tem o caminho das pedras ai? Abs

Comment: Tenho uma dica, vou precisar de um tempinho para escrever e to meio ocupado agora. No fim do dia eu mando aqui!

Comment: Uma forma que pode ajudar (não necessariamente a melhor ou mais sofisticada) seria realizar essa query assim que o sistema iniciar e deixar ela em uma variável global do seu sistema. Caso o conteúdo seja totalmente estático isso resolve, porém caso você queria dar um "dinamismo" a solução você pode configurar um celery para rodar uma função de N em N minutos que atualiza essa variável global.

Comment: Estava pensando em fazer algo parecido. Talvez gerar um json a partir da lista e atualiza-lo..  boa acho que essa será a saída por hora haha Obrigado abs!